# How to write unit testing case for classes in the grails-app/utils folder in Grails 2.3.0

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

I write a utility class in the grails-app/utils :

```
package com.demo.formatter

class FooFormatter {
    static def foo() {
        return true
    }
}
```

and, write a unit test case in the test/unit :

```
package com.demo.test.formatter

@RunWith(JUnit4)
class FooFormatterTests {
    @Test
    void testFoo() {
        AssertTrue(FooFormatter.foo())
    }
}
```

and then, run testing case with Intellij Idea IDE, but I always got the error message like following:

```
Class not found: "com.demo.test.formatter.FooFormatterTests"
```

Did I do something wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a package declaration in your test file?  Does it match the directory layout?

Comment: Yes, my package is com.demo.test.formatter

Answer (score 0):

This tests runs great in IntelliJ 12.* (test and the util class being in the same package and tested in v2.2.4)

```
@RunWith(JUnit4)
class FooFormatterTests {
    @Test
    void testFoo() {
        assert FooFormatter.foo()
    }
}
```

Try to test from `console/command` line with `grails test-app`.